# Local integration by parts formula for Call options

Tags: malliavin-calculus

I face a lot of difficulties to answer questions from past exam about Malliavin calculus and its application to finance and  more precisely the pricing of a european call (I'm a student in a Msc in Quantitative Finance at La Sorbonne).
I would be very grateful if you could help me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: i did prove in question b top to bottom but the other way seems difficult. And don't talk to me about question a

Comment: c'mon i need a little help please

Comment: the work is due on monday at midnight and i still don't know how to answer these two questions. If someone with enough goodwill (and a little knowledge of Malliavin Calculs) know how to answer these questions please contact me.

Comment: I don't know if this little document is of some help : http://math.swansonsite.com/instructional/malliavin.pdf

Comment: not really but thanks anyway